# Saving Android app QGIS and Ministro 2 with right qt libraries onto USB for installation onto tablets without internet?

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-android

I need to get the ministro 2 app onto a USB to install onto android tablets for the QGIS app to work.

I can get both apps on OK but not the required qt libraries in Ministro 2.

Reason being there is no internet where I am and I want to install this app on peoples tablets when they visit for navigation.